# ValidationSummary is not in the same order as the view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, modelstate, validationsummary

I have a standard view set up, model bound fields with required attributes and some custom modelstate.AddModelErrors however, the summary doesnt display the errors in the same order as the view.

My summary errors are as follows:

- The Title field is required.
- The First name field is required.
- The  Last name field is required.
- The Date of birth field is required.
- At least one contact number is required
- The Gender field is required.

The last 2 should be the other way around as the "At least one contact number is required" is for a field which is after Gender field on screen and also added through modelstate.AddModelErrors. Everything ese is in the correct order.

I'd expect the model errors to be in order and anything added manually to go in at the end.  Is this not the case or do I need to write my own validation summary partial?

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write your own validation summary partial.

At least that's what I had to do. I also had to derive my own class from `ModelError`, add a priority property to it, and then use that for ordering in the partial. A lot of work all in all, so think about whether you really need to do this, as in reality most users won't ever see the full list of validation errors, but just one or two messages.